# VBA Code for Transferring ACCESS Table to SQL Server

Tags: ms-access, vba

I was trying to Transfer my Access Table Data over to SQL server but I am getting an error which says

> Object Variable or With block variable not set

I've already connected my Access database with SQL server but now facing problem transferring data to SQL server with VBA code.

Can you please help me with it?

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub ADOtest()

   Dim ADOConn As New ADODB.Connection
   Dim ADOCom As New ADODB.Command


   On Error Resume Next

   ADOConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=IT-TEMP2-8470P\SQLEXPRESS2014;Database=Discrepancy;Trusted_Connection=True;"
   ADOConn.Open

   Debug.Print ADOConn.State

   Dim db As Database
   Dim Discrepancy As Database
   Set db = Discrepancy
   Dim ID As Variant

   db.Execute "INSERT INTO [ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=IT-TEMP2-8470P\SQLEXPRESS2014;DATABASE=Discrepancy].SFTransfersDB ( ID, TO ) SELECT ID,TO FROM SFTransfersDB" 


End Sub
```

I am getting error at the 2nd last line:

```
db.Execute "INSERT INTO [ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=IT-TEMP2-8470P\SQLEXPRESS2014;DATABASE=Discrepancy].SFTransfersDB ( ID, TO ) SELECT ID,TO FROM SFTransfersDB"
```

Comment: `ADOConn.Execute` instead of `db.Execute`, but you might need ACE or Jet provider to use the `[ODBC;` parts

Comment: You seem to be conflating ADO with DAO. Your ADO connection string specifies the database already, so no need for separate object. Moreover, once connected no need for distributed query clause in append query in same database.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are attempting an ad hoc distributed query. If server permits it, consider executing this statement after your ADO connection. No need for calling Access objects.

```
ADOConn.Execute "INSERT INTO dbo.SFTransfersDB ([ID], [TO])" _
           " SELECT [ID], [TO] FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', " _
           "'Data Source=""C:\Path\To\Access\Database.accdb""')...SFTransfersDB;"
```

Answer (score 1):

You declare two Database variables, but don't initialize them (you don't set them to anything):

```
Dim db As Database
Dim Discrepancy As Database
```

So this

```
Set db = Discrepancy
```

is the same as

```
Set db = Nothing
```

and so when you try to use `db`, you get the error that `db` is not set, which it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions.

I got it correct after all.

I used "Set db = CurrentDb" and it worked perfect.